# PHP Regex Match nothing

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match even when there isn't anything.
My string to match is:
Linha digitavel 999999 barra: vencimento: 07/08/2017

I've this regex:

```
preg_match("/Linha digitavel ([\.0-9\s]+) barra: ([0-9]+|\0) vencimento: (.*)/", $input, $output);
```

Works great when there's something on barra but fail if there's not.
I tried using ([0-9]+|), ([0-9]*) and ([0-9]{0,}), neither of them work.

**Test strings:**

Didn't work:

```
Linha digitavel 3083981 barra: vencimento: 07/08/2017
```

Works:

```
Linha digitavel 3083981 barra: 0303456 vencimento: 07/08/2017
```

Comment: Can you show an example line with the missing data, for clarification of the issue?

Comment: yep, sure.
Didn't work:
Linha digitavel 3083981 barra: vencimento: 07/08/2017
Works:
Linha digitavel 3083981 barra: 0303456 vencimento: 07/08/2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if the barra value is missing, there's also one less space. You need to account for this too, by making the space optional.

`preg_match("/Linha digitavel ([\.0-9\s]+) barra: ([0-9]*|\0)\s?vencimento: (.*)/", $input, $output);`

(also changed `[0-9]+` to `[0-9]*` to make it optional)

https://regex101.com/r/fV8nT9/1

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
preg_match("/Linha digitavel ([\.0-9\s]+) barra: ([0-9]+|\0)? vencimento: (.*)/", $input, $output);
```

Notice the question mark which denotes the number is optional.